# Replacing ?: conditional operator with python conditional expression

Tags: python, abstract-syntax-tree, conditional-operator, pyparsing

A tool I use has implemented the ?: operator into the python (jython) grammar. Now I want to pass code written in that tool to the AST module to analyze it.

It is not possible for me to patch python, so the AST module can understand the grammar. Hence, I am looking for other approaches.

What I think could work is to replace ?: with the conditional expression if – else from native python. However I don't know what to write into <base> of pyparsing to include every expression.

```
pyparsing.infixNotation(<base>,[
    (("?", ":"), 3, pyparsing.opAssoc.RIGHT)
                               ]
```

Since the precedence of the ?: is so low <base> has to quite literally be everything you can write in python. In pyparsing.nested_expr you could write None as a <base> for this case, but in infixNotation that is not possible.

Or is there a better approach to this. Maybe it is possible to change the grammar for the AST module, without changing how pyhton works for everyone else?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, this will be quite a task, to write a parser that will accept any Python expression (including a nested ?: ternary!). Look through the pyparsing examples and the plusminus project to see if you get any ideas. (plusminus might actually be more helpful, since it constructs pretty complete expressions).

Comment: Do you have a grammar for the tool that implements `exp1 ? exp2 : exp3` in this Python derivative? If you had that, this rewrite would be trivial. If that's missing, I assume you could pick up the [grammars-v4/python/python](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/tree/master/python/python), modify that for your needs, then use tree rewriting.